# How can I add a row to a ListView in one Fragment by clicking the button in another Fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have two Fragments: FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentA has a button and FragmentB has a `ListView` whose adapter is designed to use custom rows. I want to add a row into this `ListView` in FragmentB by clicking a button in FragmentA. I have researched some documents from Google about **communication between fragments** and I wrote some codes but I was not successful. I've tried to have in one fragment both buttons and the `ListView`. I was successful with using the adapter's `notifiyDataSetChanged()` method when the button is clicked. Hovewer, I don't know how I can solve this problem.

My `MainActiviy.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, FragmentA.ButtonClickListener{
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = { "A", "B"};    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);   
        // ViewPager's PageChangeListener.
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }        
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }        
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });        
        // Retrieve actionbar and set some properties.
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        Fragment frag1 = new FragmentA();
        Fragment frag2 = new FragmentB();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(frag1, "frag1Tag");
        fragmentTransaction.add(frag2, "frag2Tag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }   
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentB();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked() {  // IMPLEMENTATION OF INTERFACE METHOD
        FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2Tag");
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragmentB != null) {
            fragmentB.updateList();
        } else {
            FragmentB newFragment = new  FragmentB();
        }
    }       
}
```

My `FragmentA.java`:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {   
    ButtonClickListener mCallback;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Container Activity must implement this interface.
    // INTERFACE DEFINATION.
    public interface ButtonClickListener {
        public void onButtonClicked();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);           
        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (ButtonClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup vG = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,false);
        Button btn = (Button)vG.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                mCallback.onButtonClicked();
            }
        });
        return vG;   
    }
}
```

My `FragmentB.java`:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {   
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> valuesRefresh = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView list;
    MyListAdapter adapter;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        values.add("asda");
        values.add("kasd");
        ViewGroup vG = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container,false);
        list = (ListView)vG.findViewById(R.id.listView2);   
        adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(),values);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        return vG;
    }
    public void updateList(){    
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public static class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{      
        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
            this.context = context;
            for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
                this.values.add(values.get(i));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        public long getCount(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return values.size();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View list = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false); 
            return list; 
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating your fragments in your activity's onCreate, again in your pager adapter, and once more in onButtonClicked (FragmentB). You should only be creating them once. Since you are doing all of this inside your Activity, the easiest would be to keep references to your fragments in Activity fields. However, you need to make sure you handle the case of your activity getting re-created, because in this case Android will have re-created your fragments already, and you would not need to create and add them again.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, FragmentA.ButtonClickListener{
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = { "A", "B"};    
    private Fragment frag1;
    private Fragment frag2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // First check if Android has already created the fragments
        FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        frag1 = fragMgr.findFragmentByTag("frag1Tag");
        frag2 = fragMgr.findFragmentByTag("frag2Tag");
        if (frag1 == null && frag2 == null) {
            // Create and add fragments only if needed
            frag1 = new FragmentA();
            frag2 = new FragmentB();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(frag1, "frag1Tag");
            fragmentTransaction.add(frag2, "frag2Tag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ...
    }
    ...
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return frag1;
                case 1:
                    return frag2;
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked() {  // IMPLEMENTATION OF INTERFACE METHOD
        frag2.updateList();
    }       
}
```